# Populating a HashMap with an Array

Tags: java, arrays, hashmap

So I tried finding a tutorial on how to do this but nothing gets this complicated.  This is the first I am learning of HAshMaps so I am sure my solution should be easy, but I don't know how to do it.

I am trying to use an Array to populate a HashMap, and when I run the program my print out shows up null, which indicates that it isn't populating for me.  Been working on this for two days, and am really lost and confused.

I am trying to get my key "expenses" to be valued with a "type".

Edit:  I would like my case two to be a printout of 
1: groceries
2: Entertainment
3: Etc.....

```
public static void main(String[] args) throws FileNotFoundException, IOException 
{
    // TODO code application logic here
//        HashMap<String, String> map = new HashMap<String, String>();
    HashMap<String, List<Expenses>> map = new HashMap<>();
    List <Expenses> expenseType = new ArrayList();
    double amount, totalAmount;
    int cmd, year, month, date;
    String type, resp;
    totalAmount = 0;

    String fname = JOptionPane.showInputDialog("Enter the name of the budget file, none if no file");
    if (fname.compareTo("none") !=0)
    {
        FileInputStream ist = new FileInputStream(fname);
        ObjectInputStream ifile = new ObjectInputStream(ist);


    }
    boolean done = false;
    while(!done)
    {
        resp = JOptionPane.showInputDialog("Enter a command from: \n" 
                + "\t1:Add a new deduction\n"  //think its done
                + "\t2:Add a new expense\n"  //this is done, but could be made better wit
                + "\t3:Add a deposit\n"  //This is done
                + "\t4:Deduction options\n"  
                + "\t5:Expense Options\n"  
                + "\t6:Total balances in bank\n"
                + "\t7:quit");
        cmd = Integer.parseInt(resp);

         switch(cmd)
        {
            case 1:


            break;

            case 2:
            //Give the option to add new spending occurence.
            //Give option to choose from array of spending types.
            resp = JOptionPane.showInputDialog("Enter a command from: \n" 
                + "\t1: Create a new expense\n"  //done
                + "\t2: Choose from expense list\n"
                + "\t3:quit");
            int cmd2 = Integer.parseInt(resp);
            switch (cmd2)
            {
                case 1:

                 type = JOptionPane.showInputDialog("Enter the type of the expense:"); 

                    resp = JOptionPane.showInputDialog("Enter the amount of the expense:");   
                    amount = Double.parseDouble(resp);
                    resp = JOptionPane.showInputDialog("Enter the year of the expense:");
                    year = Integer.parseInt(resp);
                    resp = JOptionPane.showInputDialog("Enter the month of the expense:");
                    month =  Integer.parseInt(resp);
                    resp = JOptionPane.showInputDialog("Enter the date of the expense:");
                    date =  Integer.parseInt(resp);
//                      List<Expenses> expenses = map.get(type);
                    // Does the map have a List for type?
                    if (expenseType == null) {
                     // No. Add one.
                     expenseType = new ArrayList<>();
                        map.put(type, expenseType);
                        }
                    Expenses e = new Expenses(type, amount, year, month, date);
                    expenseType.add(e);

//                        map.put(type, new ArrayList(expenses));
                    map.put(type, expenseType);

                    break;

                case 2:

                 //Use a hashmap to search through the ArrayLIst and print out options.
                    //How do I populate the HashMap?
                 type = null;
                 List<Expenses> typelist = map.get(type); //reads from map
                 System.out.println(typelist);


            break;
    }

}

}
}
}
```

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve

Comment: If you use an `Expenses` object as the key, it means that when you look something up you give an `Expenses` object to the map it gives you back the "type." Is that what you want to do? And where is the array you talk about?

Comment: OKay I am still getting a "null" output after making the below adjustments.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Please don't use [raw types](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/generics/rawTypes.html). And, if I understand you, then you want something like

```
Map<String, List<Expenses>> map = new HashMap<>();
```

Then, to add to the `List` in the `Map` - use something like

```
List<Expenses> expenses = map.get(type);
// Does the map have a List for type?
if (expenses == null) {
  // No. Add one.
  expenses = new ArrayList<>();
  map.put(type, expenses);
}
Expenses e = new Expenses(type, amount, year, month, date);
expenses.add(e);
```

Comment: Just to clarify, the "map" is considered a raw type?

Comment: @JPHochbaum No, this `List <Expenses> expenses = new ArrayList();` is a raw `ArrayList`.

Comment: @JPHochbaum `map.get("type");` is not `map.get(type);`

Comment: @JPHochbaum Great. Now remove `type = null;` before `map.get(type);` You can null it after you get the value from the map.

Comment: But if I remove type = null, then map.get(type) becomes uninitialized.

Comment: If you have type=null; then map.get(type); you're using map.get(null); which isn't correct. Just print map, or get the keySet and iterate it.

Answer (score 1):

1) You should have this line

```
map.put(new String(type),expenses);
```

instead of

```
map.put(expenses, new String(type));
```

to get value from hashmap using key i.e. type.

2) Also remove double quotes from

```
List<Expenses> typelist = map.get("type");
```

to pass variable type.

Comment: It is also giving me the error of "type" not being initialized.  I wouldn't think that would be necessary since I have type being set in case 1.  Confused about that error.

Comment: @JPHochbaum Different question, but the compiler does not know that case 1 will always execute. Declare `type` as, `String type = null;` and that message will go away.